# Why is this Laravel Form getting GET'ed not POST'ed

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap, laravel

I am trying to save the customer values to the database via the below Laravel view PHP. If I do `Route::post('/directory', 'TaskController@store');` in the `routes.php`, then I get an Exception `"MethodNotAllowedHttpException"`. But I do `"Route::get('/directory', 'TaskController@store');"` then no exception and the correct method in TaskController is called. What I don't understand, even though I have the form method as POST, the form send with GET. I am new to Laravel, so excuse my ignorance here.

I am using Bootstrap's pager/wizard class to submit the Customer data. Not sure if that makes any difference.

```
<form action="{{url('/directory' . $Customer->id)}}" method="POST">
            {{ csrf_field() }}
            <div class="form-group">
                <ul class="nav nav-pills">
                    <li class="active"><a href="#basic-tab" data-toggle="tab">Customer Details</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#database-tab" data-toggle="tab">Directory Configuration</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <!-- Current Tasks -->
            @if (count($Customer) > 0)
            <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-heading">
                    Customer Details
                </div>

                <div class="panel-body">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="customer-name">Name</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="customer-name" value="{{ $Customer->name }}">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="customer-email">Email</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="customer-email" value="{{ $Customer->email }}">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="customer-street">Street</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="customer-street" value="{{ $Customer->street }}">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="customer-post_code">PostCode</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="customer-post_code" value="{{ $Customer->post_code }}">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="customer-country">Country</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="customer-country" value="{{ $Customer->country }}">
                    </div>
                    <!-- Previous/Next buttons -->
                    <ul class="pager wizard">
                        <li class="previous disabled"><a>Previous</a></li>
                        <li class="next"><a href="/directory">Next</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
            @endif
        </form>
```

Comment: what did you do with the `route` when the form is submitted? Did you use `Route::post('YOUR_URL', 'CONTROLLER@FUNCTION');`

Comment: It looks like the following is will always send a GET `<ul class="pager wizard">
                        <li class="previous disabled"><a>Previous</a></li>
                        <li class="next"><a href="/directory">Next</a></li>
                    </ul>`. So now I have added Buttons and it seems to send a POST request. And in my Respository, I have the save method with only parameter of Request. In that method, I can't seem to find any of the posted data. Any idea what could be reason?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the following will always use GET (I believe due to the `<a>` tag), even though the form method is set to POST in the form tag.

```
<ul class="pager wizard">
<li class="previous disabled"><a>Previous</a></li>
<li class="next"><a href="/directory">Next</a></li>
</ul>
```

So I replaced the `<a>` tag, with a `<button>` tag, and the form seems to get POST'ed fine.

Answer (score 0):

Route::post('Yoururl/{id}', 'YourController@Save');